# Decide which of the following indicated functions $f$ are homeomorphisms and which are not. Show clearly why or why not.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set

My partial solution is wrong, can someone please help me with this? I know we need to show bijection and continuous but not sure how.

Let $C$ denote the Cantor set, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology. For $\sigma \in C$, write $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots)$ where $\sigma_i \in \{0, 1\}.$ Decide which of the following indicated functions $f$ are homeomorphisms and which are not. Show clearly why or why not.

(a) $f: C\to C$ given by $f((\sigma_1, \sigma_2,\sigma_3, \dots)) = (1-\sigma_1, 1-\sigma_2, 1-\sigma_3, \dots)$

(b) $f:C\to C\times C$ given by $f((\sigma_1, \sigma_2,\sigma_3, \dots)) = ((\sigma_1, \sigma_3, \sigma_5, \dots),(\sigma_2, \sigma_4, \sigma_6,\dots))$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ To show homeomorphic, we must show that the function $f$ is injective and surjective. Our Cantor set C, can be described as the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ having ternary expansions using only the digits $0$ and $2$; real numbers of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n},$$ where each $a_n$ is either $0$ or $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you have to show that the functions are injective, surjective and that the functions and their inverses are continuous with respect to the relevant topologies. I leave injectivity and surjectivity to you. As for continuity, the open sets in the product topology on the Cantor space $C = \{0, 1\}^{\Bbb{N}}$ are those of the form $A = X \times \{0, 1\}^{\Bbb{N}}$ where, for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $X \subseteq \{0, 1\}^n$, i.e., $A$ is the set of sequences $(a_i)$ determined by some finite set of constraints on the $a_i$. Intuitively, this means that a continuous function $f : C \to C$ is a function that only needs to "read" a finite part of its input to determine any given finite part of its output (and similarly for $f : C \to C \times C$ or $f : C \times C \to C$).

Answer (score 2):

Forget the ternary expansion, that is a justification why we can call $C=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ the Cantor set (which is traditionally defined as a subspace of $[0,1]$, not an infinite product).

A fundamental fact about the product topology:

> A function $F:X \to Y=\prod_i Y_i$ is continuous, where $Y$ has the product topology (and projections $\pi_i: Y \to Y_i$) iff $\pi_i \circ F: X \to Y_i$ is continuous for all $i$.

For your map in $a)$ note that $\pi_n \circ f$ is just the map $1-\pi_n$, which is indeed continuous for all $n$, and for $b)$ note that each component map is just itself an infinite "product" of projections, so again continuous (by a second application of the fact). Both maps are clearly bijections and continuity is now clear, so compactness does the rest.

Comment: Thank you. Compactness as in closed and bounded?

Comment: @rudinsimons12 [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space). In the reals or $\Bbb R^n$ in *the standard metric* this is equivalent to closed and bounded. Here we have product spaces.

Comment: +1: but, I guess compactness **and the Tychonoff theorem** does the rest (I got told off for an implicit appeal to Tychonoff here the other day, so I'm feeling sensitive about that, $\ddot{\smile}$).

Comment: @RobArthan A mild version of Tychonoff, if you even want to go that route. Compactness of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ only does not need choice.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: sure: I was being light-hearted. The continuity of the inverses is easy  without appealing to compactness by a slight rejigging of your appeal to the universal property of the product topology or from first principles about the product topology.

Comment: For a) let $B$ be the canonical base (basis) for $C$,  comprising all $\prod_{n\in \Bbb N}B_n$ where each $B_n\subset \{0,1\}$ and $\{n:B_n\ne \{0,1\}\}$ is finite. We have $\{f[b]:b\in B\}=B.$

Comment: Thank you @HennoBrandsma I asked because I feel like there is so many working definitions of compactness in topology

Comment: Thank you for the help! @DanielWainfleet